# Load all data after a specific observation

Tags: stata

Using [this](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1402453-import-large-file) excellent advice from Statalist, I am running a loop to read in a `60GB` Stata dataset and save it in chunks (after some data preprocessing).

Unfortunately, I do not know the total number of observations and so the `use` command does not execute when asking to read in more data than is available:

```
use `usevars' in 210000001/220000000 using "a_large_dta_file.dta", clear
```

The dataset appears to contain less than `220000000` observations, but I do not know how many. I am looking for an `endoffile` operator or something in that spirit to circumvent this problem. Manually I verified that at least `210001001` exist, but this will not help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following reproducible example using Stata's `auto` toy dataset:

```
sysuse auto, clear
display _N
74
```

Using the `describe` command will get you what you want:

```
findfile auto.dta

describe using "`r(fn)'" // or ask for only one variable e.g. describe rep78

display r(N)
74
```

Stata datasets are always rectangular so you can also manually load a single variable and count:

```
use rep78 using "`r(fn)'", clear // load a variable which also contains missing data

display _N
74
```

Alternatively, use a loop to load smaller chunks and  the `capture` command to see where it fails.